# How to add Google fonts library with angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, google-font-api, angular-builder

I added Google fonts link in `styles.scss` file of Angular project.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700');
```

But It already works with Angular CLI command `ng serve`, but,  trying to build up command `ng build --prod --base-href` deployed the project. Then noticed the issues.

The issue is it "didn't work with import google font".

I'm researching for this issue on google. but I didn't find a good solution.

I want to know how do apply the google font in an angular project?

Comment: I always link these in the head of index.html and have not had an issue?

Comment: It should work if you add the link in `<header>` of your `index.html` file. There could be a url or path reference error  when you build it with `--base-href`

Comment: Please instance for me ?

Comment: you think. build your project local and run it. , how to use that command `ng build --prod --base-href`

Comment: can you share screenshot of network tabs of chrome developer tool to see if browser actually send request for fonts?

Comment: Clear your browser cache and app data.  I just tested this with and without using --base-href /test/ and it works fine.

Comment: Beautifully explained here https://golb.hplar.ch/2019/06/google-fonts-download.html

Comment: @RedAnz How did you finally sorted this ? I am batteling the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

**This is best way to use google font locally with angular 2,4,5,6,7 and more**, First Download Google Font and this in inside the assets folder and use it is as per your requirement.

In angular.json call this in src/assets

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets"
 ],
```

In css file add this font-face in top

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  src: url(/assets/Montserrat/Montserrat-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-weight:300;
}
```

At Last use it as per your requirement like

```
body{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: [link](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts) It is a convenient little helper to select the fonts you like from google.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to include your own version of Roboto font from google inside your angular app

`npm install roboto-fontface`

then inside your angular.json file add the font file in the styles list
like this

```
"styles": [              
          "node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css"
        ],
```

Comment: or put it in styles.scss `@import "~roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css";`

Comment: Could this be used with any Google Font??

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

in `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <app-root>
        Loading...
    </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have u added as given above??

Comment: your code and my code same, but one thing is different, that is `<base href="">`. '<base href="/">' When the project is implemented the project does not work

Comment: can u remove base and just use simple link instead. its working fine for me.